# Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp-provisioning

I am getting below error message when I tried to apply a xml template to SharePoint Online site:

> *powershell_ise.exe Error: 0 : 2018-11-29 08:11:45.1338   [Fields]    [11]    [Error] Adding field {a1cde222-ddcd-4bbe-b63b-72375b2c0b6e} failed: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. :    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryRetry(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay, String userAgent)
>      at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.ObjectField.CreateField(Web web, XElement templateFieldElement, PnPMonitoredScope scope, TokenParser parser, String originalFieldXml)
>      at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.ObjectField.ProvisionObjects(Web web, ProvisioningTemplate template, TokenParser parser, ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation applyingInformation) 41904ms 16f2e9ad-3d29-4abc-8515-3ead1b368e7f
>   powershell_ise.exe Information: 0 : 2018-11-29 08:11:45.1338    [Fields]    [11]    [Debug] Code execution scope ended  41904ms 16f2e9ad-3d29-4abc-8515-3ead1b368e7f
>   powershell_ise.exe Information: 0 : 2018-11-29 08:11:45.1338    [Provisioning]  [11]    [Debug] Code execution scope ended  48757ms 16f2e9ad-3d29-4abc-8515-3ead1b368e7f*

Any ideas what causes this error and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Viktor

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. What cmdlt were you using?

Comment: can you add your template/xml details, related to  field {a1cde222-ddcd-4bbe-b63b-72375b2c0b6e}?